# Ajax response as Map Object to bind to Html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting the Result Data Set as **Map Object**. I am using the script below to append the data to Html. But it was not affecting.

```
$("#district").change(
        function() {
            $('#mandal').html('');
            var district = {
                "district" : $("#district").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url : "Reports",
                data : JSON.stringify(district),
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                type : 'POST',
                async : true,
                success : function(res) {
                    console.log(res.resList.length);
                    for ( var i = 0; i < res.resList.length; i++) {
                        console.log("Kalishavali " + res.resList[i]);
                        $('#mandal').append(
                                '<option value=' + res.resList[i] + '>'
                                        + res.resList[i]
                                        + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Result Data Format:

```
{08=Prakasam, 09=S.P.S Nellore, 04=East Godavari, 05=West Godavari, 06=Krishna, 07=Guntur, 13=Kurnool, 01=Srikakulam, 11=Kadapa, 02=Vizianagaram, 12=Anantapur, 03=Visakhapatnam, 10=Chittoor}
```

This is My Jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@include file="includes/Header_1.html" %>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#district").change(
        function() {
            $('#mandal').html('');
            var district = {
                "district" : $("#district").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url : "Reports",
                data : JSON.stringify(district),
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                type : 'POST',
                async : true,
                success : function(res) {
                    console.log(res.resList.length);
                    for ( var i = 0; i < res.resList.length; i++) {
                        console.log("Kalishavali " + res.resList[i]);
                        $('#mandal').append(
                                '<option value=' + res.resList[i] + '>'
                                        + res.resList[i]
                                        + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>


         <s:select label="District" list="resList" listKey="key" value="value" name="district" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select District"/>
         Mandal :
    <select id="mandal"></select>
```

Comment: So what is the issue with your logic

Comment: seems invalid response, that is not json.

Comment: the code is not appending that means the data is not appending to mandal id tag.....

Comment: Response is Map<String,String>  Object

Comment: you can use EHTML for mapping json result to html: https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML

Answer (score 0):

The response is not valid JSON :

1. the key value pairs are separated by `=` instead of `:`
2. there are no quotes around them

Should be :

```
{"08" : "Prakasam", "09" : "S.P.S Nellore" etc...}
```

Comment: the response is like this  {08=Prakasam, 09=S.P.S Nellore}

Comment: please suggest me where can i change code to get correct result please............

Comment: The best way to correct your problem is to change the server's response, so that it produces valid JSON. If you can't modify the server-side code, then you will have to parse the response some other way, for example using regular expressions, but that's a different question.